# GDATA Feed API - Parsing Timestamps in PHP

Tags: php, youtube, feed, gdata

I'm currently using YouTube's feed API to get information about a YouTube channel's uploaded videos. An example feed would be something like http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/google/uploads?v=2

Timestamps in the feed are in the format `2011-04-27T20:54:42.000Z`. How would I convert that to something more readable, like `April 27th, 2011 at 8:54:42pm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DateTime::createFromFormat` to create a new DateTime object from that format, then you can output it however you want using the object's `format` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/function.strtotime.php), which converts a string into a UNIX timestamp, and [date](http://www.php.net/manual/function.date.php), which converts a timestamp into human-readable output:

```
echo date( 'F dS, Y \a\t h:i:sa', strtotime("2011-04-27T20:54:42.000Z") );
```

[Live example](http://codepad.org/HrQUWxJw)